# Speech to text automatically starts when textfield begins to edit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I don't know the specific name for this button, but it is the one with the microphone that when you press it, it allows you to speak, and it will convert your speech into text.

I haven't been able to find anything on this, but when I click to edit a textfield I want that button to be pressed automatically so I can just begin to speak and then click done so that it will convert the audio to text.

I don't know if this is possible and can't seem to find anything on it... Probably because my search is weak since I have no idea how to ask it.

If anyone knows how to do this, or knows where there is anything on it, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Can't you call your button action on textFieldDidBeginEditing: method??

Comment: I can call it in that method. But I have no idea how to call the action.

Comment: You can call the action same as all other method.. like [self yourActionName];

Comment: This button is on the keyboard.

Comment: When you press that button from keyboard you will do some action no? Put that action in a new method and call it whenever you want..

Comment: Could you give me an example of it. I have been looking for something like that for the dictation button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot do that.**

That is a part of Siri.

Till now Apple not provided any api to interact with siri.